# Qt 5 library missing

Tags: c++, qt5, exe

I was trying to compile using **MinGW's windeployqt**. As parameter I put my **.exe** file and when I try to start my application it tells me that the `libgcc_s_seh-1` library is missing. So I try to add it manually and it gives me the same error of the previous post:

`The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b).`

How can I fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

windeployqt can be a tricky customer: It picks its information where to find the Qt libraries from the %PATH% variable in Windows. If you have two or more Qt / mingw instances installed, this might end up in a unhealthy mixture. Replace the wrong path to mingw in the environment by the correct value.

Comment: On %PATH% of Windows I have only one MinGW installation in **C:\MinGW\bin** and that's it, I don't have any Qt directory.

Comment: Edit: if I change the PATH from **C:\MinGW\bin** to the Qt5 MinGW it gives an error.

Comment: Is there a blank in the path to your Qt installation? Move the binaries and libraries to c:/qt/... in this case.

Comment: Fixed using another MinGW cmd.